# Running a long command

Tags: output

What's the best command that allows me to do this:

1. send the output of say `ls` to a file called `etcdir`
2. Print out the etcdir file using `cat`
3. Print out the exit status using `echo $?`
4. Breaking up the command into two lines.

I know its something like

`sudo ls > etcdir && cat etcdir ??? \ echo $?`

or

`sudo ls > etcdir && cat etcdir; \ echo $?`

~thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine step 1 and 2 by using `tee` which copies output to a file instead of redirecting it, so that it will still be visible in terminal.

Here would be your commands:

```
ls | tee etcdir
echo $?
```

Comment: If this answer solves your question, please accept it by clicking the grey check button on its left. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.